# Junit ErrorCollector usage - failure does not show

Tags: java, junit, junit4, errorcollector

I have several assertion and I would like to collect all the problems and finally the whole test should fail with proper console output. But right now, I do not have anything.

```
    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();
    Matcher<Boolean> matchesTrue = IsEqual.equalTo(true);

collector.checkThat("FAILURE","BLA".equals("OK"), matchesTrue);
collector.checkThat("FAILURE","BLABLA".equals("OK"), matchesTrue);
```

After the run, everything is green and no error on the console.

What is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks valid. The following test ...

```
public class ErrorCollectorTest {

  @Rule
  public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

  @Test
  public void testErrorCollection() {
    org.hamcrest.Matcher<Boolean> matchesTrue = org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo(true);

    collector.checkThat("FAILURE", "BLA".equals("OK"), matchesTrue);
    collector.checkThat("FAILURE", "BLABLA".equals("OK"), matchesTrue);
  }
}
```

... produces this output:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: FAILURE
Expected: <true>
     but: was <false>

    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:956)
    at org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector$1.call(ErrorCollector.java:65)
    at org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector.checkSucceeds(ErrorCollector.java:78)
    at org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector.checkThat(ErrorCollector.java:63)
    ...


java.lang.AssertionError: FAILURE
Expected: <true>
     but: was <false>

    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:956)
    at org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector$1.call(ErrorCollector.java:65)
    at org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector.checkSucceeds(ErrorCollector.java:78)
    at org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector.checkThat(ErrorCollector.java:63)
    ...
```

This is verified with JUnit 4.12 and Hamcrest

Comment: Very strange, NO error on the console, however the collector contains all assertionerror but not presented on the console... Using the evaluate expression tool, a simply checkThat result is undefined.

Comment: I decided, I marked it glitch as an answer but for me it does not work. Probably, I extended my test class because It is necessary for me, and in this case error collector does not work.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Junit 5 (Jupiter), you need the following additional dependency that allows the `@ErrorCollector` rule to work:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-migrationsupport</artifactId>
        <version>${jupiter.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Following that, you need to include the `@EnableRuleMigrationSupport` annotation at your test class level.

Comment: Its working. But for extended classes, we need to pass errorCollector object from the parent test class.